# WebSocket works on PC but not on Android?

Tags: android, websocket, arduino, esp8266, okhttp

I'm trying to communicate with an ESP8266 WiFi chip from an Android device using WebSockets to remotely control some motors connected to an Arduino. First I prototyped using a PC & Python & set up a WebSocket server on the ESP8266...

**ESP8266_server.ino**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>

const char* ssid     = "SKYNET";
const char* password = "yourdogsauntsmaidenname";


WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t lenght) {

    //Serial.printf("[%u] get Message: %s\r\n", num, payload);

    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:      
            break;

        case WStype_CONNECTED: 
            {
              IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
             // Serial.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\r\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);    
            }
            break;

        case WStype_TEXT:
            {
              //Serial.printf("[%u] get Text: %s\r\n", num, payload);
              String _payload = String((char *) &payload[0]);             
              Serial.print(_payload);           
            }   
            break;     

        case WStype_BIN:
            {
              hexdump(payload, lenght);
            }
            // echo data back to browser
            webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, lenght);
            break;

    }
}

void setup() {

  // Set up serial comms
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set up WiFi 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    // Serial.print(".");
     delay(200);
  }  
//  Serial.println("");
//  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
//  Serial.println("IP address: ");
//  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  delay(500);  

  // Set up web socket
//  Serial.println("Start Websocket Server");
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}
```

The WiFi chip is connecetd via a serial connection to an Arduino Mega which in turn parses the data to control some H-bridges for 2 DC motors. The Arduino also relays the data to the Arduino IDE serial monitor.

**motor_control.ino**

```
//  Serial comms from Wemos EPS8622 to Arduino Mega

#include "SoftPWM.h"

// Outputs to PWM & H bridge direction
// PWMs: 
// DC_pwm, left_pwm, right_pwm = 3, 4, 5
int pwm_out[] = {3, 4, 5};
const int num_pwm = sizeof(pwm_out) / sizeof(pwm_out[0]);

// H bridge direction control: 
// right_2, right_1, left_2, left_1, dc_2, dc_1  = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11
int dir_pins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11};
const int num_dir_pins = sizeof(dir_pins) / sizeof(dir_pins[0]);

// Input buffer from ESP8266
int in_buff[] = {0, 0};
const int num_in_buff = sizeof(in_buff) / sizeof(in_buff[0]);

void setup() {

  // Set up serial comms
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Debug to Serial Monitor
  Serial3.begin(115200);  // From ESP8266

  // Set up PWM pins
  SoftPWMBegin();
  for (int i = 0; i < num_pwm; i++)
  {
    SoftPWMSet(pwm_out[i], 0);
  }

  // Set up H bridge direction pins
  for (int i = 0; i < num_dir_pins; i++)
  {
    pinMode(dir_pins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(dir_pins[i], LOW);
  }
}

void loop() {

  // Check input from EPS8266 & send it to the H bridges
  while (Serial3.available() < num_in_buff){}

  if (Serial3.available()) {
      // read the incoming bytes
      // in_buff[0] - direction flags
      // in_buff[1] - PWM
      Serial.println(".......");
      Serial.println("In from ESP8266");
      for (int i = 0; i < num_in_buff; i++){
        in_buff[i] = Serial3.read();
        Serial.println(in_buff[i]);
      }
      Serial.println(".......");
  }

  // Set direcions on H bridges
  Serial.println("Direction pins");
  for (int i = 0; i < num_dir_pins; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(dir_pins[i], bitRead(in_buff[0], i));
    Serial.print("pin ");
    Serial.print(dir_pins[i]);
    Serial.print(" : ");
    Serial.print(digitalRead(dir_pins[i]));
    Serial.println();
  }

  // PWM to motors
  for (int i = 0; i < num_pwm; i++)
  {
    SoftPWMSet(pwm_out[i], in_buff[1]);
  }
}
```

On the PC side I have some Python code that is set up as a WebSocket client that takes user input from the terminal & transmits to the ESP chip.

**motor_control_WiFi.py**

```
"""
Motor control over WiFi using Wemos EPS8266 & Mega board

Motor H-bridge direction flags
    Both forwards     - b'111001, d'57, ASCII 9
    Both backwards    - b'110110, d'54, ASCII 6
    Clockwise (right) - b'111010, d'58, ASCII :
    A/Clock (left)    - b'110101, d'53, ASCII 5

"""

from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient
import time, requests
import struct

esp8266host = "ws://192.168.1.84:81/" 

class DummyClient(WebSocketClient):
    def opened(self):
        print("Websocket open")
    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        print("Connexion closed down", code, reason)
    def received_message(self, m):
        print(m)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ws = DummyClient(esp8266host)
        ws.connect()
        print("Ready !")
        direction = ""

        while direction != "q":

            direction = input("Direction: ")

            if direction == "f":
                payload = "9"
            if direction == "b":
                payload = "6"
            if direction == "r":
                payload = ":"
            if direction == "l":
                payload = "5"

            ws.send(payload)
            time.sleep(.20)

            pwm_out = int(input("PWM: "))
            pwm_out = struct.pack('<B', pwm_out)
            ws.send(pwm_out)
            time.sleep(.20)


        print("Finished, close Websocket connexion now and exit script")
        ws.send("0:0")
        ws.close()
        exit()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.send("0:0")
        ws.close()
```

This all works fine. So my next step was to make an Android app to do what my Python code is doing. I'm using the `okhttp3` library & added `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'` to the Gradle build file & added internet permissions to the manifest.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package qdivision.org.websocketexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okio.ByteString;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button start;
    private TextView output;
    private OkHttpClient client;

    private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            //webSocket.send("l");
            webSocket.send(ByteString.decodeHex("23"));
            webSocket.send(ByteString.decodeHex("32"));
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "Goodbye !");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            output("Receiving : " + text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
            output("Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
            output("Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            output("Error : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        client = new OkHttpClient();

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void start() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://192.168.1.84:81").build(); //"ws://echo.websocket.org"
        EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }

    private void output(final String txt) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                output.setText(output.getText().toString() + "\n\n" + txt);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="qdivision.org.websocketexample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start !"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/start"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When this is deployed I dont get any connection errors. The sent bytes are echoed back to the display & the client disconnects with no error. BUT I get no feed back via the Arduino Serial Monitor that anything has been sent!

What's missing here? How come no connection error if the bytes are not being sent/recieved?

**Edit #1** I ran the Python code on the Android device from the Termux command line. The code runs, says the socket is open & lets me input direction & PWM but still nothing from the serial monitor.

**Edit #2** I can ping the ESP8266 from the Android device using Termux with 0 package loss but still no data being sent by either the Python code or the app.

**Edit #3** Python code now works from the Termux command line on the Android device (no idea how I made no changes, it just works now??!!??). The `okhttp3` based app still sends no data.

Comment: StackOverflow's policy is to post a minimum working example. This is usually a good debugging technique too - bisect the problem until you find the culprit. Try connecting your ESP and Mega to a some logging device (Logic Analyzer, Serial-to-PC adapter, whatever) and get some debug output from the ESP and if needed, also monitor Mega.

Comment: @mostanes the code in the post is as stripped back as I could get it to reproduce the problem (I am well aware of Sos policies). If you had read the code/post you would see that the data is being logged by the Arduino Serial Monitor which is how I found the problem in the first place.

Comment: Urgh, that is still very large. I suppose your Mega runs "motor_control.ino". Could you directly connect the ESP to a logger? What's the logger output then? If your websockets run on unencrypted http, see if you can run some network packet capture software (ex. Wireshark) on a PC connected to the wireless network and monitor the network packets exchanged between the Android device and the ESP (note that you will need to run Wireshark in promiscuous mode). Given the problem domain, you will definitely want "motor_control.ino" and "activity_main.xml" out of the loop.